# Shareoint 2013 Add left side navigation to the blog layout

Tags: html, css, asp.net, layout, sharepoint-2013

I would like insert Left Navigation in my Blog View in Sharepoint 2013.

It's OK for top navigation but Left Navigation is hidden in blog view in Sharepoint 2013...

[image: left navigation]

Someone would have an idea to successfully do this?

Thanks

Comment: I would assume it's as simple as setting "Quick Launch" to enabled for your blog page.

Comment: The left navigation is already enable because when i go on a site page the left navigation appears... The problem is just on blog views...

Comment: So when viewing your blog, and you click the gear in the top-right, go to Site Settings > Look & Feel > Tree View > Enable Quick Launch is checked? If so, then I don't know what else to try.

Comment: @TylerH Yes all checkbox are checked